# How to play video on google colab with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I am working on a project related to object detection using Mask RCNN on google colab. I have a video uploaded to my colab. I want to display it as a video while processing it at the runtime using openCV. I want to do what `cv2.VideoCapture('FILE_NAME')` does on the local machine. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found I way to do it. But it is very slow.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output, Image
import base64

def arrayShow (imageArray):
    ret, png = cv2.imencode('.png', imageArray)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(png)
    return Image(data=encoded.decode('ascii'))

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_SOURCE)
while video_capture.isOpened():
    success, frame = video_capture.read()

    clear_output(wait=True)
    img = arrayShow(frame)
    display(img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

The code does not play video exactly. It just displays the new frame and removes the old frame from output.

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into the same issue. Although I do not believe there is a way to show a 'real time' video like you could locally, what you can do instead is to render a single frame at a time and display that in the notebook's output.

Unlike the OP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59496548)  this does not encode the image and it does not clear the previous frame from the console.

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import cv2

# Download sample video
!curl -o sample.mp4 https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('sample.mp4')
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, image = cap.read()

    if not ret:
      break

    cv2_imshow(image) # Note cv2_imshow, not cv2.imshow

    cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

This [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=zo9YYDL4SYZr) might be helpful, or [the code above as a notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/marcelvanworkum/b6cf8c82ee8ce40770b95527a7c37626/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=iU_0F2SVW4Yb).

Comment: i want to play all video in single time at collab, do you have that code snippet??

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
cv2_imshow(img)
```

Comment: Can you explain - what can the OP expect after using this snippet?

Comment: @ArunVinoth I have answered my own question.

Comment: This doesn't work for videos in colab, only for images

Answer (score 0):

```
from IPython.display import HTML
from base64 import b64encode

video_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Data_proc/ball.mp4'

mp4 = open(video_path, "rb").read()
data_url = "data:video/mp4;base64," + b64encode(mp4).decode()
HTML(f"""
<video width=400 controls><source src="{data_url}" type="video/mp4">
</video>""")
```

Comment: This answer does not explain why it works, how can one learn from it?

Comment: it is code to play video in colab. You have to render a video player in colab before playing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been programming in python for a few weeks...
I work with industrial automation and in my work
I don't have a development environment for python available, so I use colab
the code below was used for me to run video by cv2
I hope I helped someone

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while cap.isOpened():
#while True:
  ok, frame = cap.read()

  if not ok:
    break

  if ok:
    #edit your video size here, to adjust the performance
    largura=frame.shape[1] 
    altura=frame.shape[0]
    lamenor=int(frame.shape[1]/5)
    altmenor=int(frame.shape[0]/5)
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (lamenor,altmenor))

    # as you read
    clear_output(wait=True)
    cv2_imshow(frame)
    #delay time to update frame
    time.sleep(1.1)

  if cv2.waitKey(1100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

...

Edited...

Modified part to make it more fun if you change the source to a webcam

Original:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
```

Modified:

```
#0 = webcam position in your webcams
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#or cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

And this part for flip/mirror the frame:

```
frame2 = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

# as you read
clear_output(wait=True)
cv2_imshow(frame)
cv2_imshow(frame2)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the command on google colab :
  `ret, frame = input_video.read()`
Wish yhis help you